# Co-related Queries using lambda expressions

Tags: linq, lambda

How can I convert this LINQ query from query syntax to method syntax? I am performing a co-related query operation.

```
 var query = (from r in objEntities.Employee
              where r.Location == (from q in objEntities.Department 
                                   where q.Location == r.Location 
                                   select q.Location).FirstOrDefault()
              select new
              {
                  FirstName = r.FirstName,
                  LastName = r.LastName,
                  Age = r.Age,
                  Location = r.Location
              });
 GridView1.DataSource = query;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to lambda expression"?

Comment: @usr He wants to know how to convert his query from query syntax to method syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to convert the query to method-based query instead of syntax-based query.

```
var query = objEntities.Employee
                       .Where(e => e.Location == objEntities.Department
                                                            .Where(d => d.Location == r.Location)
                                                            .Select(d => d.Location)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault())
                       .Select(e => new {
                                            FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                            LastName = e.LastName,
                                            Age = e.Age,
                                            Location = e.Location
                                        });
```

I'm also pretty sure your inner expression within `where` clause could be replaced with something like that:

```
                   .Where(e => objEntities.Department.Any(d => d.Location == e.Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries always have performance issue instead you should use join:

In the lambda expression query should be

```
var query = objEntities.Employee.Join(objEntities.Department, E => E.Location,
                                 D => D.Location,
                                (E,D) => new {                                          
                                                FirstName = E.FirstName,
                                                LastName = E.LastName,
                                                Age = E.Age,
                                                Location = E.Location
                                             });
```